# Publish JavaDoc on Jenkins with maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, javadoc

I have maven project that is built by Jenkins-CI.
How to generate and publish JavaDoc on Jenkins?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Make sure Jenkins javadoc plugin is installed.
   Go to http://yourjenkinsserver.com/jenkins/pluginManager/installed to see list of intalled plugins.
   Plugin page https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Javadoc+Plugin
2. Configure Jenkins job:
   In Build section, Goals and options line add:

   javadoc:javadoc

That's all. No need to change pom.xml

[image: Jenkinsns job view]

Comment: I needed to use javadoc:aggregate in order for them to be published

Comment: with `javadoc:javadoc` the link is available for each module.  with `javadoc:aggregate` it is back to the project status page.  See https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9140

Comment: Can I do both a build and a javadoc at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is to create a separate task that runs thr javadoc command, and which runs after the compile task. You pass it the input and output directories.

I would run a separate tomcat for your CI website - it's easier.

Comment: I think this answer is for Ant, not Maven.

Comment: agreed - this sounds like an ant answer