# How to use javadoc in a a Jenkinfile pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to use this: [Publish JavaDoc on Jenkins with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016574/publish-javadoc-on-jenkins-with-maven) in a scripted pipeline

Answer (score 0):

For example to publish a JavaDoc: you can try something like:

```
// Define the pipeline
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    // Stage to compile the project and generate the JavaDoc
    stages {
        stage('Compile & generate JavaDoc') {
            steps {
                // Compile the project
                sh 'mvn compile'
                
                // Generate the JavaDoc
                sh 'mvn javadoc:javadoc'
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Stage to publish the JavaDoc
    stages {
        stage('Publish JavaDoc') {
            steps {
                // Publish the JavaDoc
                sh 'mvn javadoc:jar'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate and publish the Javadoc in one only stage, the stage would be like that:

```
stage ('Documentation') {
  steps {
    sh "mvn -f path/to/pom.xml javadoc:javadoc"
  }
  post{
    success {
      step $class: 'JavadocArchiver', javadocDir: 'path/to/target/site/apidocs', keepAll: false
    }
  }
}
```

Remember that if your `pom.xml` is in root directory, you do not need the `-f` option.